# Плавное разворачивание div'а

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть ли способы **плавно** развернуть div? при условии что:

1. содержимое div'a - текст произвольного объема
2. изначально div уже отображает какую-то часть этого текста, т.е. у него заданы `{overflow:hidden; height: 100px;}`

Решение должно быть кроссбраузерное, появление скрола недопустимо.

Основная проблема - получить высоту содержимого div'a ,а дальше все просто - [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Так получить высоту содержимого div'а можно на jQuery: $("#some-div").height();
Это так, мысль вслух...

Comment: @metazet, посмотрите на пример кода в моем ответе, если перед вызовом `$(this).animate({height: $(this)[0].scrollHeight}, 200);` вывести `console.log($(this).height())` то она будет равна 30, т.е. установленнному в css значению! А мне нужно узнать какова была бы высота дива, если я бы не вводил ограничение в 30 px, эта высота мне нужна чтобы организовать плавное изменение высоты div'a.

Comment: @GLAGOLA, а что Вам мешало обернуть текст в обёртку и брать её высоту? Т.е. <div style="height: 30px; ..."><div id="wrapper">текст</div></div>  
И потом уже $("#wrapper").height();

Comment: @metazet хм ... да, так тоже можно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем я нашел решение своей проблемы:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Changer</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div style="height: 30px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#E00;"> 
            sadfasdfasdf<br/> 
            asdf<br/> 
            asd<br/> 
            f<br/> 
            asd<br/> 
            f<br/> 
            asd<br/> 
            f<br/> 
            asd<br/> 
        </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $('div').click(function () {
                // console.log($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
                $(this).animate({height: $(this)[0].scrollHeight}, 200);
            });
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Как отметить свой ответ как правильный?

Comment: Через 2 дня появится галочка :) Особенности портала...